Problems with real snow - The texture is too big
I've been having this problem where my real snow is absolutely huge, but it's actually fine on my other objects. For example, I have no idea why it's huge and have tried to scale it down to no avail.


I'm guessing your objects don't have a scale of 1 ? Then, Ctrl+A > Scale
